# directx - shade in plane surface with lighting off

Tags: directx, hlsl

I have an plane surface(all the z of vertexes equal to 0.0) with many vertexes, and attached the texture on it with lighting off by:

```
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false);
```

And there are shades in the render result.

I tried to turn off the normal too:

```
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, false);
```

It doesn't work also.

Does anybody know what's going on?

---

I just want the texture shows distorted without any light effect.
And the surface is from tessellated NURBS control points.

---

The color of texture seems changed by VertexShader, is that possible? and how to solve it?

---

The pure white texture rendered like below:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2318704/image/effect.png

---

question is changed to [directx - texture render result is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400167/directx-texture-render-result-is-incorrect)

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem is nothing about HLSL, this question is changed to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400167/directx-texture-render-result-is-incorrect

Comment: instead of moving a question, please consider editing your original question